# How to count paragraphs in a text file

Tags: ruby

Using the [oliver.txt](http://hills.ccsf.edu/~dputnam/oliver.txt)
write a method called `count_paragraphs` that counts the number of paragraphs in the text.

In [oliver.txt](http://hills.ccsf.edu/~dputnam/oliver.txt) the paragraph delimiter consists of two or more consecutive newline characters, like this: `\n\n`, `\n\n\n`, or even `\n\n\n\n`.

Your method should return either the number of paragraphs or nil.

I have this code but it doesn't work:

```
def count_paragraphs(some_file)
    file_content = open(some_file).read()
    count = 0
    file_content_split = file_content.split('')

    file_content_split.each_index do |index|
        count += 1 if file_content_split[index] == "\n" && file_content_split[index + 1] == "\n"                      
    end
    return count
end

# test code
p count_paragraphs("oliver.txt")
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Gustavo, please don’t ask questions here if you’re going to then disappear for days, weeks or maybe forever.

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to either count it directly:

```
file_content.split(/\n\n+/).count
```

or count the separators and add one:

```
file_content.scan(/\n\n+/).count + 1
```

Comment: Where should I do that?

Comment: Your solution will match a leading paragraph separator.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the number of paragraphs there is no need to construct an array and determine its size. One can instead operate on the string directly by creating an enumerator and counting the number of elements it will generate (after some cleaning of the file contents). This can be done with an unconventional (but highly useful) form of the method [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub).

**Code**

```
def count_paragraphs(fname)
  (File.read(fname).gsub(/ +$/,'') << "\n\n").gsub(/\S\n{2,}/).count
end
```

**Examples**

First let us construct a text file.

```
str =<<BITTER_END


Now is the time
for all good
Rubiest to take
a break.


Oh, happy
day.

One for all,
all for one.


Amen!
BITTER_END
```

```
  # "      \n\nNow is the time\nfor all good\nRubiest to take\na break.\n      \n     \nOh, happy\nday.\n\nOne for all,\nall for one.\n\n   \nAmen!\n"
```

Note the embedded spaces.

```
FNAME = 'temp' 

File.write(FNAME, str)
  #=> 128
```

Now test the method with this file.

```
count_paragraphs(FNAME)
  #=> 4
```

One more:

```
count_paragraphs('oliver.txt')
  #=> 61
```

**Explanation**

The first step is deal with ill-formed text by removing spaces immediately preceding newlines:

```
File.read(fname).gsub(/ +$/,'')
```

```
  #=> "\n\nNow is the time\nfor all good\nRubiest to take\na break.\n\n\nOh, happy\nday.\n\nOne for all,\nall for one.\n\n\nAmen!\n"
```

Next, two newlines are appended so we can identify all paragraphs, including the last, as containing a non-whitespace character followed by two or more newlines.<sup>1</sup>.

Note that files containing only spaces and newlines are found to contain zero paragraphs.

If the file is known to contain no ill-formed text, the operative line of the method can be simplified to:

```
(File.read(fname) << "\n\n").gsub(/\S\n{2,}/).count
```

See [Enumerable#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) and [IO#read](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-i-read). (As `File.superclass #=> IO`, `read` is also in instance method of the class `File`, and seems to be more commonly invoked on that class than on `IO`.)

Note that `String#gsub` without a block returns an enumerator (to which `Enumerable#count` is applied),

Aside: I believe this form of `gsub` would be more widely used if it merely had a separate name, such as `pattern_match`. Calling it `gsub` seems a misnomer, as it has nothing to do with "substitution", "global" or otherwise.

<sup>1 I revised my original answer to deal with ill-formed text, and in doing so borrowed @Kimmo's idea of requiring matches to include a non-whitespace character.</sup>

Comment: `str.scan(/\S+\n{2,}/).count`, no need to gsub.

Comment: @KimmoLehto, `scan` produces a temporary array, something I wished to avoid, as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about a loop that memoizes the previous character and a state of being in or outside of a paragraph?

```
def count_paragraphs(some_file)
  paragraphs = 0
  in_paragraph = false
  previous_char = ""
  File.open(some_file).each_char do |char|
    if !in_paragraph && char != "\n"
      paragraphs += 1
      in_paragraph = true
    elsif in_paragraph && char == "\n" && previous_char == "\n"
      in_paragraph = false
    end
    previous_char = char
  end
  paragraphs
rescue
  nil
end
```

This solution does not build any temporary arrays of the full content so you could parse a huge file without it being read into memory. Also, there are no regular expressions.

The `rescue` was added because of the "Your function should return either the number of paragraphs or nil" which did not give a clear definition of when a nil should be returned. In this case it will be returned if any exception happens, for example if the file isn't found or can't be read, which will raise an exception that will be catched by the `rescue`.

You don't need an explicit `return` in Ruby. The return value of the last statement will be used as the method's return value.

Comment: True that. Replaced the solution.